# Как объединить несколько json

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте. Есть несколько совершенно одинаковых по структуре json.

Нужно получить из них данные и вывести в цикле.
Для получения данных из первого json делаю:

```
$content = shell_exec('curl -s --digest -u лог:пасс http://сервер.запрос');
$json = json_decode($content);
$json_users = $json->oscam->users;

foreach ($json_users as $u) {
    //тут вывод значений
}
```

Тут все просто. Но есть еще json:

```
$content2 = shell_exec('curl -s --digest -u лог:пасс http://сервер2.запрос');
$content3 = shell_exec('curl -s --digest -u лог:пасс http://сервер3.запрос');
```

Как вывести значения всех этих json в одном цикле? как будто бы это все один большой json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получите данные, декодируйте, объедините нужные массивы в один, потом сделайте вывод

в общем случае,

```
$cfg = ['http://сервер.запрос', 'http://сервер2.запрос', 'http://сервер3.запрос'];

$users = [];
foreach($cfg as $url){
     $content =  shell_exec("curl -s --digest -u лог:пасс $url");
     $json = json_decode($content);
     $users = array_merge($users, $json->oscam->users);
} 

foreach ($users as $u) {
    //тут вывод значений
}
```

зы: несколько странно, конечно, использовать `shell_exec`, который потенциально будет запрещен на хостинге, в то время как с curl можно работать штатными средствами пхп

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно. по поводу `shell_exec` в курсе, использую скрипт на сервере :)